# How to Align Adsense Ads exactly on center of page with with Exact Pixels down from Top and Above Bottom

Tags: javascript, html, css, adsense

Its though a generic question
Refer this URL

```
    http://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/narendra-modi-and-barack-obama-a-us-india-partnership-for-the-21st-century/2014/09/29/dac66812-4824-11e4-891d-713f052086a0_story.html
```

The adsense ads are showing after some content
I am wondering is there any div or css class to find out center of the page to show ad or a script which count the number of characters of the content and show ad after specified count of words

Is it possible to show ad in between exactly basis the pixel of the page.
Say 600 px down from top and exactly aligned on center of the page. Can some one guide css class to mark an ad exactly on predefined pixels at center of the page

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add div and make it center by align them

try to add below css to div which contain adsense align:xxpx auto will center the div.

```
.adsense div{
  top:600px;
  align:XXpx auto;
}
```

Comment: sorry doesnt work. I want a container exactly on center of page then can add adsense code to it. But above code does not add container to center of page or to 600 px below top of the page.

Comment: Try to use fix div and locate any where in you page